# ASP.NET session expire time

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I want to set the session life span to 2h, but i'm not sure how.
If I set the `<sessionState timeout="120" />` in web.config I still get logged out every few minutes. Am I setting it wrong ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your timeout is mostlikely not session but authentication, look for the below line and change that:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".EMSOLG_ASPXAUTH" timeout="120" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session timeout in codebehind like this

```
Session.Timeout = 120;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have hosted the website in IIS , you can configure the required timeout in IIS.